# Cassandra CREATE CUSTOM INDEX ERROR java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

-> Table :

```
cassandra@cqlsh:coba> CREATE TABLE data(
        ... nim int,
        ... nama text,
        ... alamat text,
        ... PRIMARY KEY (nim, alamat)
        ... );
```

-> Make Index :

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX cari_alamat ON coba.data (alamat) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
```

-> Error :

```
ServerError: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex
```

-> I would be very happy if you can help me

-> Thanks You

Comment: What version of cassandra are you running?

Comment: In Cassandra 3.4 and later, a new implementation of secondary indexes, SSTable Attached Secondary Indexes (SASI) is available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As initially susspected, I think you are running cassandra version lower than 3.4.

(that's why I asked for the version)

I tried it out and got the same error on 3.0.10:

```
cqlsh:test> CREATE CUSTOM INDEX cari_alamat ON test.data (alamat) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
ConfigurationException: Unable to find custom indexer class 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
```

Theoretically you could implement your own with:
[Cassandra Custom Secondary Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449800/cassandra-custom-secondary-index)

But I guess it's just easier to upgrade.

Also be aware there might be some bugs with Sasi indexes:

[SASI Indexes in Cassandra seem to have some bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290270/sasi-indexes-in-cassandra-seem-to-have-some-bugs)

But I guess it's better to search cassandra Jira for this one, this is just as a small warning.