# SASI index in cassandra showing erros

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-sasi-index

I am new to cassandra. Whech i check that sasi is very useful to query espesially in where cluase. But i got an error showing

```
ConfigurationException: Unable to find custom indexer class 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
```

My cassandra verion is 3.0.9

Does any body can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be running Cassandra version lower than 3.4 for Sasi index to work.
Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43467081/3582996